# What are the effective permissions if a setuid program is executed via sudo?

Tags: linux, sudo, setuid

I have read many questions and answers about how the `setuid` bit works and about how `sudo` works, and I think I have understood that stuff.

However, I couldn't find out what should happen when a program is executed via sudo *if that program itself has the `setuid` bit set*. The question is best explained by an example:

On the system in question, there is a user called `user1`. The system has `sudo` installed and configured correctly so that the `root` user can execute programs as whichever different user he wants. Furthermore, there is a program `/usr/bin/exampleprog` which is owned by `root:wheel` and has the `setuid` and `setgid` bits set:

```
root@morn ~ # dir /usr/bin/exampleprog
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root wheel 92K 2017-11-16 23:42 /usr/bin/exampleprog
```

Now I login *as root* and execute the following command:

```
root@morn ~ # sudo -u user1 /usr/bin/exampleprog
```

What happens then? Does `exampleprog` run as `user1` (as could be expected from the options given to `sudo`), or does it run as root (because the executable is owned by root and has its `setuid` bit set)?

To make things more complicated, there is an additional program `/usr/bin/wrapper`, also owned by `root:wheel`, but *without* the `setuid` and `setgid` bits:

```
root@morn ~ # dir /usr/bin/wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 15K 2017-11-16 23:42 /usr/bin/wrapper
```

The `wrapper` program, when being executed, at some point executes (spawns) `/usr/bin/exampleprog`.

Now I execute:

```
root@morn ~ # sudo -u user1 /usr/bin/wrapper
```

When `wrapper` spawns `exampleprog`, will the latter run as `user1` or as `root`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can experiment with this by copying the `id` program somewhere, and changing its permissions. This will show that `exampleprog` runs with an effective uid of root, and a real uid corresponding to `user1`.

Consider what would happen if you logged in as `user1` and ran `exampleprog`: since the latter is suid root, you’d expect it to run with an effective uid of root. The same applies when you run the program through `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. I would have expected this, but I am having a weird situation here where things seem to behave differently. Now knowing how they *should* behave, I can investigate further. Also thanks for the hint regarding `id`; I didn't know about it until now. I'll report back when I know more ...

Comment: OK, I've found the problem: The program I was executing via `sudo` indeed had its `setuid` and `setgid` bits set, and therefore began execution as `root:wheel` when starting, but immediately dropped its privileges afterwards, thus again becoming the user and group who involved it (that is, the user and group which had been set by the `sudo` options `-u` and `-g`). I didn't know that this program drops it privileges during startup, and therefore I thought that `sudo` would override the `setsuid` mechanism somehow (although I was wondering how that could be possible). Thanks again!